# Dynamic Row-Level Security in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, powerbi, ssas, azure-analysis-services, row-level-security

I have a model with two table : 1 fact table called Sales and 1 Dimension table called Employees. The employees table has a fullname and an email column (among others). Now I want to make a PBI dashboard where every employee can only see his own Sales.

These employees connect to PBI*/Azure using their email. And I want to implement a dynamic RLS tabular in Azure Analysis Services (Cube level) and not in every PBI report.

How do I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

PBI*  Power BI

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation, which is a very good summary of how to do this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-tutorial-row-level-security-onprem-ssas-tabular and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it :

1. Roles
2. Create a Read role
3. At the row filters I did on the Employee Table : 'Employee'[Email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()